# How can I connect Heroku to Github?

Tags: github, heroku

I have had a Github account for about 3-4 months.  Just today, I added an 'Organization'.  I changed the security settings for this Organization, and now it says 'No Restrictions'.  Here's an image.

[image]

I followed the instructions from the link below, to get that setup.

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/enabling-oauth-app-access-restrictions-for-your-organization

Now, I am trying to link Keroku to my Github account.  In the Keroku environment, I click 'Connect to Github' and I get this.

[image]

I followed the instructions in the link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgNcs9zlFSA

Somehow, the lady can connect in 2.5 minutes, but even after working on this for 60 minutes, all I get is error saying Keroku can't connect to Github.  Does anyone know exactly how this works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very, very bizarre.  I tried the same steps in Google Chrome and everything worked just as I expected it to.  For some weird reason, I couldn't get it to work in Firefox.  Anyway, everything works fine now.